# WSO2 mi create a pipline

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We use the mi, publisher, carbon.
I want to create a pipeline for the mi. This pipeline create a car file from the code base. and deploy the car file to mi.

I try to mvn -e clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true and deploy the car file but is not working.
I am waiting for the true car files.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want to pipeline the code base to the car file. @ycr

Answer (score 0):

A sample  CI/CD pipeline for deploying CAR files in Micro Integrator has been described in the following documentation. You can use the Integration Project created in Studio to implement this pipeline.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/deployment/mi-cicd-vm/